# a pivot table kinda group by

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables, table1: containing customer details, table2: containing uniq codes, table3: containing 1 row for every single item purchased. The number of items purchased are from 1 to n.

table1: data is imported every few minutes as business goes along
ID, account, emailaddress, transactionID

table2:
ID, uniqcode

table3: data is imported every few minutes as business goes along
ID, account, transactionID, item

I do a join on incrementing ID's which will give me something likes this:
select * from table1
join table3 on table1.transactionID = table3.transactionID
join table2 on on table3.ID = table2.ID

this results in:

emailaddress1, item1, uniqcode1
emailaddress1, item2, uniqcode2
emailaddress1, item3, uniqcode3
emailaddress2, item1, uniqcode4
emailaddress2, item2, uniqcode5

I would like to end up with a result like this
emailaddress1, item1, uniqcode1, item2, uniqcode2, item3, uniqcode3
emailaddress2, item1, uniqcode4, item2, uniqcode5, null, null

Why the hassle? Because our bulkmailer can only cope with 'flat' tables and I'd like to send 1 email containing the number of uniq codes (they'll get 1 for every item purchased) they are entitled to instead of a number of emails containing a single code. The codes are provided by a third party. All this needs to be done in mssql. A view will be used to let the bulkmailer think it's actualy looking at a single table.

How can i do this???

Comment: Your bulk mailer can only process _one_ row at a time? But it can deal with an indefinite (and varying) number of columns in the row? Sounds dubious...

Comment: If it can handle multiple rows, generate one joined row per ordered product, sort by customer (or by transaction ID-- why is it in the customer table?), and tell the mailer to read rows till the customer changes.

Comment: Not exactly. The view will be limited to a max of 12 items. A campaign can only read or compose a message from 1 table... 1 message equals the information in 1 row...

Comment: You could try doing 12 left joins in a row... this is bad, bad, bad design...

Comment: Hahahaha, only because it can be done. No, I think I'll have to find another way to acomplish this...